# Класс для изменения имени файла

Tags: php

Где может быть ошибка?
Все параметры функции `move_uploaded_file` выводятся и получаются правильно:

```
class Picture {      

            protected $uploaddir = IMAGE_MAIN_P;
            public $uploadfile;            
            public $realNameFile; 
            public $path;

            public function replaceName($timeName){
                $this->realNameFile = time().'.png';  //меняет название файла                                  
            }     

            public function upload(){          

                $this->realNameFile = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
                $this->replaceName($this->realNameFile); // updated file name                
                $this->uploadfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$this->uploaddir.basename($this->realNameFile);                
                var_dump($this->uploadfile);
                $this->path = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
                var_dump($this->path);

                move_uploaded_file($this->path, $this->uploadfile);            
           }


}

if (isset($_POST['upload'])){     
    $picture = new Picture();     
    $picture->upload();
}
```

Comment: ООП ради ООП? «$this->replaceName() = $new;» — что это? «$this->realNameFile = $realNameFile = time().'.png';» — что это? У функции есть аргументы, через них «пробрасывается» внутрь функции значения. Как использовать в другом месте мы не подскажем, пока не скажете, где надо использовать. Может, вам статичный метод нужен? А может и нет.

Comment: при вызове `upload` нужно что бы срабатывал метод `replaceName` и менял имя переменной

Comment: $this->replaceName($this->realNameFile); — это вызов, правда, не ясно зачем передаётся свойство класса. Значение вы меняете внутри этого метода: «$this->realNameFile = time().'.png';» — имя переменной не надо менять. А вот название файла в этом коде нигде не меняется. Смотрите в сторону [http://php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php](перемещения файла).

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае, [загрузка файла (без защиты)](https://habrahabr.ru/post/44610/) выглядит так:

```
$uploadfile = 'uploads/' . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "File uploading failed.\n";
}
```

Давайте добавим немного автоматизма в код. Я честно не понимаю, зачем вам ООП-подход для такой задачи, так что не буду извращаться и писать эти функции так.

```
function getNewFileName() {
    return 'uploads/' . time() . '.png';
}

function saveUploadFile($tmpName) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($tmpName, getNewFileName())) {
        echo true;
    } else {
        echo false;
    }
}
saveUploadFile($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);
```

Если используете ООП-подход, то помните об абстрагировании.

Answer (score 1):

или так :

```
$uploads_dir = '/uploads';
foreach ($_FILES["pictures"]["error"] as $key => $error) {
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES["pictures"]["tmp_name"][$key];
        $name = $_FILES["pictures"]["name"][$key];
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
    }
}
```

А чтобы переименовать и даже перенести есть нативная функция :

```
rename("/tmp/tmp_file.txt", "/home/user/login/docs/my_file.txt");
```